# Browse Yii Relations with limits

Tags: yii, relational-database, yii-cmodel

I have a `Community` model and a `Content` model. Each `Content` has a `community_id` column. I created this simple relation:

```
$relations['contents'] = array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Content', 'community_id','order'=>'weight DESC, id DESC');
```

(note the ORDER)

In the `CommunityController` I want to display say the top 20 Contents (then in another ajax action get the next 20, no worries about that).

I could probably do it via Criteria, something like:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('community_id',$model->id);
$criteria->limit = 20;
$criteria->order = 'weight DESC, id DESC';
$contents = Content::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But the code looks overkill to me (too long) and I feel like I'm not using at all the Relation I created. Is there a simpler way? Or am I looking for problems where there aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your relation as a method and pass criteria there:

```
$contents = $model->contents(array('limit' => 20));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CActiveRecord::getRelated()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getRelated-detail) and add your new criteria as the last parameter. Your code might look something like

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->limit = 20;
$contents=$model->getRelated('contents',true,$criteria);
```